# SQL Server Add integer variable to end of string

Tags: sql-server

I want to generate some integers in SQL Server loop and add it to end of string that is a long number

```
Declare @i int
Set @i = 10

While @i < 45
Begin
    insert into AllowedStudents (GroupID, StudentNumber) 
    values ('1', '9210410' + @i)

    SET @i = @i + 1
End
```

but when insert process ends I see this result :

```
28240   1   9210420
28241   1   9210421
28242   1   9210422
28243   1   9210423
```

against

```
28240   1   921041020
28241   1   921041021
28242   1   921041022
28243   1   921041023
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `@i` from `int` to `varchar`

Like this

```
insert into AllowedStudents (GroupID, StudentNumber) 
values ('1', '9210410' + Convert(varchar(50), @i))
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3c98/2)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of type precedence in SQL Server. `Int` datatype has higher precedence than `varchar` datatype, causing `varchar` to be implicitly converted to `int` type. You need to explicitly convert your `int` variable to `varchar` datatype.

This can be done with `cast` or `convert` functions:

```
'9210410' + cast(@i as varchar(100))
```

or

```
'9210410' + convert(varchar(100), @i)
```

For more information on datatype precedence visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx